# Problems trying to use the C++ auto type for object attributes (member variables) and deducing the return type of std::bind

Tags: c++

I have the following code which attempts to generate a random hexadecimal digit.

```
#include <random>
#include <functional>


using std::mt19937;
using std::uniform_int_distribution;


class
RandomHexDigitGenerator
(
    public :

        // Other functions omitted for the sake of brevity.

        RandomHexDigitGenerator
        (
        );

        char
        generateRandomHexDigit
        (
        );


    private :

        mt19937                       * rng_p;

        mt19937::result_type            seed;

        uniform_int_distribution<int> * distribution_p;  // Map values onto range [0, 15]

        // The following declaration will cause a problem since
        // the compiler won't be able to deduce its type.

        auto                            rhvg;
);
```

The definitions of two of the methods are as follows;

```
// Constructor for class.

RandomHexDigitGenerator::RandomHexDigitGenerator
(
)
{
    this->seed           = time(0);

    this->rng_p          = new mt19937(this->seed);

    this->distribution_p = new uniform_int_distribution<int>(0, 15);

    // The following line of code will also be problematic.

    this->rhvg           = std::bind(* this->distribution_p, * this->rng_p);
}


char
RandomHexDigitGenerator::generateRandomHexDigit
(
)
{
    int   randomHexValue;


    randomHexValue = this->rhvg();

    return(this->convertHexValueToHexDigit(randomHexValue));
}
```

My problem with the code, is the bind operation which is performed in the Constructor. I don't know what its return type is, which is why I declare rhvg to be auto. The trouble is - as per my understanding, that the compiler needs to be able to deduce the type of rhvg when it first encounters it within the class declaration!

So my question is, how can I solve this problem? Will the type which is returned by the bind operation be horrible, and thus I shouldn't even bother trying to work out what it is? Should I continue to use auto but in another manner? Is templating the class an option, or is templating a convoluted solution for a not so difficult problem?

In case it matters, I am using GNU g++ under Linux Mint ver 19.2, and the output of the `g++ -v` command is as follows;

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-5 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10)
```

Finally, my Makefile makes use of the `-std=c++11` compiler switch in the correct place.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume you are referring to std::bind. Please add what compiler you are using and what version of C++ (if you know it). As it looks like the std::bind return type isn't, or hasn't always been part of the C++ specification. Also, please add what you have already done to figure out the answer.

Comment: Why would you use `std::bind` here, with objects of known type and a call that you control?  Just call the distribution with the generator when you need to, no?

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but why all the blank lines? Also, you don't need to write `this->` everywhere, and don't parenthesize return expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is way more convoluted and verbose than I'm comfortable with. Here's what I would do:

```
#include <random>
#include <ctime>
    
class RandomHexDigitGenerator
{
  public:
    char generateRandomHexDigit() {
        return static_cast<char>(dist(rng));
    }
  private:
    std::mt19937 rng{static_cast<std::mt19937::result_type>(std::time(0))};
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist{0, 15};
};
```

No `new`, no `bind`.

Returning to the question as posed, you cannot have a non-static class member of the type "unknown-result-of-bind". You can have `std::function` instead, but this doesn't make any sense, here's why.

`bind` stores its arguments by copy, so if you do this

```
std::function<char(void)> rhvg;
rhvg = std::bind(distribution, rng);
```

you don't need `distribution` and `rng` members any more because they are copied to `bind`. So you can create those in the constructor instead.

```
class RandomHexDigitGenerator
{
  public:
    char generateRandomHexDigit() {
       return rhvg();
    }
  private:
    std::function<char(void)> rhvg = std::bind(
      std::uniform_int_distribution<int>(0, 15),
      std::mt19937(static_cast<std::mt19937::result_type>(std::time(0)))
    );
};
```

but why have a class for this? You can wrap everything in a function instead:

```
std::function<char(void)> makeRandomHexDigitGenerator() {
  return std::bind(whatever);
}
```